# Javamail Pop3 Session timeout?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to use javamail to download a mailbox of 1000 messages of hotmail. 
The problem is after an hour or so, I get a Pop Session timeout exception, and I can't fetch messages anymore.

```
C: TOP 3210 0
S: +OK 1444 byte(s)
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0zLjQuMDt1cz0wO2k9MDtsPTA7YT0x
X-Message-Status: n:0
X-SID-PRA: Super Wall <apps+ocdlfcez@facebookmail.com>
X-SID-Result: Pass
X-Message-Info: R00BdL5giqoqgO8FeGWl8Lch6n3is6BT1wNitKPj0Jb+fghk1p9MsC+MFGyB2nflerotq/xZ5r8LiguM+3GjEOSj3umkoXeU
Received: from mx-out.facebook.com ([204.15.20.140]) by bay0-mc7-f15.bay0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.2668);
     Tue, 8 Apr 2008 15:14:55 -0700
Received: from api.facebook.com (intlb01-mip1.sctm.tfbnw.net [10.1.240.6])
    by mx-out.facebook.com [email018.sctm.facebook.com] (8.13.6/8.13.6) with ESMTP id m38MEtOg030239
    for <xgameprogrammer@hotmail.com>; Tue, 8 Apr 2008 15:14:55 -0700
X-Facebook: from zuckmail ([168.143.164.188]) 
    by api.facebook.com with HTTP (ZuckMail);
Date: Tue, 8 Apr 2008 15:14:55 -0700
To: Ahmed Saleh <xgameprogrammer@hotmail.com>
From: Super Wall <apps+ocdlfcez@facebookmail.com>
Reply-to: Facebook <apps+ocdlfcez@facebookmail.com>
Subject: You just received a new photo from Lejla Boric
Message-ID: <03df95f3306af0a88432e7fcca22f7ac@api.facebook.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: ZuckMail [version 1.00]
X-Facebook-Notify: platform_email
Errors-To: apps+ocdlfcez@facebookmail.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="b1_03df95f3306af0a88432e7fcca22f7ac"
Return-Path: apps+ocdlfcez@facebookmail.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 08 Apr 2008 22:14:55.0926 (UTC) FILETIME=[F9D6A560:01C899C5]


.
C: RETR 3210
S: -ERR POP3 session timed out
javax.mail.MessagingException: No inputstream from datasource;
SentDate : Wed Apr 09 01:14:55 AST 2008
  nested exception is:
```

Comment: Talk about privacy... However, in answer to question, don't you think an hour or so accessing the same POP session is a bit excesive? I doubt it purely down to your code, rather than fact that most email servers will have time limits built in! Although, I'm not sure how what you have posted could help resolve your problems... If you restart the application after receiving the exception, can you access the POP server once again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, this is just a simple case of the session timing out. Like anything, the mail server will have a time limit to prevent excessive access, which is how would describe downloading emails for over an hour!

There is nothing wrong with your code, your just asking too much of hotmail / the mail server!

Though, just some friendly advice: the next time you ask a question here on SO, please don't post irrelevant information like you have done here. In cases like yours, it is helpful to see atleast a snippet of the code that is responsible for that part of the application that is functioning incorrectly and any exceptions - we'd also need to see the line(s) of code mentioned in the stack trace... However, a start would be to actually ask a question instead of this stating a fact, like you have done here!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I didn't post any relevant codes, because I guessed that there is nothing wrong with my code.